# Will Allah forgive me for my sins (drinking and not regularly praying Salah)

Tags: death, forgiveness

If somebody prays the Friday(Jumua'h) prayer and seeks forgiveness from Allah(SWT) and dies in that week while he drank alcohol and had the intention to drink again and whether he did have the intention to pray the coming Friday prayer for repentance for all sins including the drinking and hoping forgiveness and all other sins.

If he would die that week so **can there be** forgiveness because of the intention to pray the coming Friday prayer knew there is a possibility he would die in that state while sinning and was very afraid of getting tormented in the grave because of dying in that state.

So will this person be granted 100% forgiveness by Allah (swt) and will not get tormented in the grave?

Comment: Ah! I'm sorry but the question is too big. I guess... It can also be opinion based.

Comment: asking questions such a way would not attract quality answers... :) Learn how to ask...

Answer (score 1):

salaam u alaikum
look, it is known the the consumtion of alcohol is HARAAM-forbidden, no matter what, so if the person knows this, then they are to abstain from it completely. i'm not going to provide all the evidence (hadeeth and quranic verses), as it will take long, but i will just get to the point. regarding prayer, the person shouldnt wait for friday prayer to ask for forgivness, start asking from now!!! the Five daily prayers are to be established as soon as you hit the age of seven, but if someone hasnt been praying then they should start as soon as possible, and yes, i have heard that any duah which is made between the adhaan and iqama is accepted, and Allah knows best. you shouldnt worry about dying intoxicated, because if you are reading this and sober right now, then just dont ever drink again, and make the intention in your heart to stop for the sake of Allah SWT. Start praying from now, and asking Allah for forgiveness. noone can say Allah wont forgive you, and noone can say He will, that is completely known by Him the All mighty and All merciful. Just have hope in your heart that Allah will forgive you, and have fear that He wont, and remember, we are all judged according to our intentions. :) if you like, my email is tash.chamma@gmail.com, so if you have issues or anything, or need help with anything, i can help, In Sha llah
May Allah SWT have mercy on us all and save us all from the torment of the grave and in the hereafter, Amen